# How do I append a list to a file in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to append a list of strings to a file in VimL
Here is my workaround code:

```
let lines = ["line1\n", "line2\n", "line3\n"]
call writefile(lines, "/tmp/tmpfile")
call system("cat /tmp/tmpfile >> file_to_append_to")
```

Any way to append to the file directly in vim?
There should be, but I can't find anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `readfile()`+`writefile()`.

If you are using Vim 7.3.150+, (**or** if you are absolutely sure that file in question ends with `\n`):

```
function AppendToFile(file, lines)
    call writefile(readfile(a:file)+a:lines, a:file)
endfunction
```

For Vim *older than* 7.3.150:

```
" lines must be a list without trailing newlines.
function AppendToFile(file, lines)
    call writefile(readfile(a:file, 'b')+a:lines, a:file, 'b')
endfunction

" Version working with file *possibly* containing trailing newline
function AppendToFile(file, lines)
    let fcontents=readfile(a:file, 'b')
    if !empty(fcontents) && empty(fcontents[-1])
        call remove(fcontents, -1)
    endif
    call writefile(fcontents+a:lines, a:file, 'b')
endfunction
```

Comment: I'm confused by your last sentence. `:h readfile()` says that without 'b', "Whether the last line ends in a NL or not does not matter." (Vim 7.4.26)

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes Update to version 7.2.446 (commit http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=9577a28005e10fab0a0cada6c41b96c9a3e1bfe9). Note that file must contain exactly no newlines to see the bug (empty list returned by `readfile()`). Also note that it may be not the last version with a bug.

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes It was fixed in version 7.3.150 (Apr 01 2011). AFAIR when I was writing this I just used my experience with `readfile()`, VAM and version 7.2* that was stable without rechecking. It was July 4 2010 when I modified VAM to always use `readfile(, 'b')` and most recent version at the time was 7.2.445 (apart from changes in vim73 branch). I definitely was using Gentoo (either stable or `~arch`) meaning that I had more or less slightly outdated version. Does not matter though as bug resided until 7.3.150.

Answer (score 6):

The `write` command can be used to append the entire current buffer to a file:

```
:write >> append_file.txt
```

You can limit it to range of lines in current buffer if you want.  E.g., this would append lines 1 through 8 to end of append_file.txt:

```
:1,8write >> append_file.txt
```

Comment: This is a much better and easier way of doing things.

Comment: Visual selection made, `:'<,'>w >> test.txt` results in `"test.txt" 3L, 119C appended`.  This is definitely the answer I was looking for.  (Note: unlike shell append, the file must already exist!)

Answer (score 5):

Vim 7.4.503 [added support](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=094a87e76155fcbb43f7070eb605c2944192a7ff) for appending to a file with `writefile` using the `"a"` flag :

```
:call writefile(["foo"], "event.log", "a")
```

From `:h writefile`:

```
writefile({list}, {fname} [, {flags}])
    Write |List| {list} to file {fname}.  Each list item is
    separated with a NL.  Each list item must be a String or
    Number.

    When {flags} contains "a" then append mode is used, lines are
    appended to the file:
        :call writefile(["foo"], "event.log", "a")
        :call writefile(["bar"], "event.log", "a")
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be useful, but it appends content to current file.

Create an array removing `\n` from each field.

```
:let lines = ["line1", "line2", "line3"]
```

And append at the end to current file:

```
:call append( line('$'), lines )
```